# It would be correct to use the NavigationDrawer to open Activities, not fragments?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

My application basically has one main activity. Within it there are three tabs, each with a fragment. Something similar to the layout of whatsapp.

To add more functionality to the application, I saw that the NavigationDrawer would be a good option. But because of my application running with a main activity with children fragments, I wonder if it would be a bad practice loading activities and not fragments, when the User clicking on any item NavigationDrawer.

Or does the best meneira would turn my MainActivity in a fragment? It would give me a great job ..

I would like to suggestions =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `NavigationDrawer` to open new activities. Basically just make each of the Activities have the same-looking Drawer and the user experience will be same as if you were replacing `Fragments`.

However, I would discourage this. I have been working with apps that mixed `Fragments` and `Activities` for the `NavigationDrawer` and the outcome was problematic, especially when it came to backtracking and saving state. It did work, but required hackfixing and some illogical code.

The best practice for the `NavigationDrawer` is to have one "container" activity which does little more that just exchanging `Fragments` in a `FrameLayout` it holds. The rest of the logic would be in the Fragments. This way the app is easily extendable and the backstack is handled by the platform.

Comment: So if I choose to use only fragments, in my case the application basically has one main activity, and within it there three tabs, each with a fragment. The best way would be to take the TabLayout my main_activity.xml. Making the ViewPager the main_activity.xml, puts them within a fragment and and add them (TabLayout and ViewPager) only when the 'home' application?

That would be the way 'right'?

Comment: Yes, you should put the current Pager logic in another Fragment, somewhat creating a Activity=>Fragment(Pager)=>Fragments(content) hierarchy when the "Home" option is selected.

Comment: Thank you so much. Their responses have left things clearer =) That's necessary for now

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `Fragments` but there is no problem to open new `Activities`. Instagram does something similar. It has tabs (I know that you want to use `NavigationDrawer`, but this is just a example), and one on these tabs open a new `Activity`, with the X button to close the `Activity`.

Instagram Main Activity:

[image]

New Activity with close button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Series Guide](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/SeriesGuide) Android application does exactly the same. It opens Activities from the Navigation Drawer. Such Activities extend the [BaseNavDrawerActivity](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/SeriesGuide/blob/dev/SeriesGuide/src/main/java/com/battlelancer/seriesguide/ui/BaseNavDrawerActivity.java). The Activity's start and exit animations are custom to make the transition looking smoother.

I would recommend this approach since it's much more easier to manage Activities' back stack than Fragments'.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed happily with opening activity as well. Make sure you put the back button on the opened activity so that user would have clear idea that which screen is the primary.

**But wait..**

If you are worried about whether you are following the standards (industry) or not then read below:
If all your activity has the equal importance for users (including the tabbed one) then recommended way is to use the fragments and on the other side if you don't want people to get distracted by navigation drawer icon or tabs then better to open a new activity with just a back button on top..

I hope it would give you idea how to proceed..